# onChange Summernote make input uppercase

Tags: onchange, text-editor, summernote

I want to make an event onChange in Summernote text editor that will change input in the texteditor to uppercase on change. The codes are as follow.

**HTML**

```
<div id="dSummernote">test</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#dSummernote').summernote({
    height: 200,
    onChange: test
});


function test()
{
    console.log($('#dSummernote').toUpperCase());
}
```

unfortunately it's not working =)

This is the jsfiddle created for it
http://jsfiddle.net/gw8xpwhp/140/

Answer (score 0):

Simple anwser (not the only one):
 `console.log($('#dSummernote').text().toUpperCase());`

`toUpperCase()` methods you use on any string or non-string value. Non-string value will be converted to string.

I like to see effect without looking at console, so I add `div`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="dSummernote">test</div> 
<div id='changes' class='clsChanges'></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function test() 
  {
  let content = $('#dSummernote').text().toUpperCase();
  $('#changes').text(content);
  }
```